# How to select only a few columns in my NHibernate query?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a one class to one table mapping; unfortunately this table has 110+ columns, and queries take a long time process, especially when most of the time I only want to view <10 columns.

My problem is that the queries are dynamically generated based on what the user wants to look at. I can't really create different mappings with different columns because there would be a very large number of combinations. I'm using the criteria API to generate the queries. Can I also use this to only select the columns the user wants? Or some other method?

Thanks

Comment: What did you say 110 columns ? back to the drawing board !

Comment: @V4Vendetta "What? Redesign my precious database? I spent years on perfecting its structure and no one will tell me what to do with it!!!" (c) Your Client...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `ProjectionList` to select the columns you want. [See here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection) for the examples.

Comment: If the link dies, the answer is kinda useless. Include a small, but essential, snippet along with links ...

Answer (score 17):

Easy to do with LINQ (assuming you're using NHibernate 3.0 or later):

```
var products = from p in Session.Query<Product>()
               where // ...some query (snip)
               select new
               {
                   Name = p.ProductName,
                   Description = p.ShortDesc,
                   Price = p.Price,
                   Units = p.Quantity
               };
```

Also, if you're using HQL, you can just select the columns you need similar to using T-SQL, but use a `Transformer` to get a strongly typed object back:

First create a class with your narrowed down columns:

```
public class ProductReport
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Units { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query:

```
string hql = "select p.ProductName as Name, p.ShortDesc as Description ...(snip) " +
             "from Product p " +
             "where ...some query (snip)";

IQuery query = Session.CreateQuery(hql)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ProductReport>());

IList<ProductReport> products = query.List<ProductReport>();
```

Just sure make the aliases in your query (as Name, as Description etc.) match the property names in your class.

Comment: Doesn't help when I have 100+ potential columns/properties with any combination. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the example Tim gave you can do something like this:

```
IList selection =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>()
        .Select(
            c => c.Name,
            c => c.Age)
        .List<object[]>();
```

Above example was taken from: [http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx](http://web.archive.org/web/20110925063131/https://www.nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)